# CocoaPod Storyboard error:

Tags: xcode, storyboard, cocoapods, podspec

I made a cocoapod to include in my main project, it was the splash screen animations which would be used while the app was loading which page to go to. Everything builds fine in the cocoapod project, but when I include the local copy in my other projects local folder, i get the following error on the storyboard...

```
error: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?
```

Any idea on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with my .podspec file. I had my .source_files spec including not only my swift file, but also my storyboard.. which apparently xcode is not cool with (shown below)..

```
spec.source_files = 'cocoaPodProjectFolder/Source/*.{swift, storyboard}'
```

To fix this I had to move the storyboard file to its correct spec: resource_bundle...

```
spec.source_files = 'cocoaPodProjectFolder/Source/*.{swift}'
spec.resource_bundle = {'CocoaPodProject' => 'cocoaPodProjectFolder/Source/*.{storyboard}'}
```